# GRUB cannot install after upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Last year, I converted my MBR SSD drive to GPT and enabled UEFI on BIOS even **My old laptop does not support UEFI completely!** and it was working until today. **I'm afraid if I cannot boot it again...**

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 20.10 using this command:

```bsh
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

My computer shutted down and when I turned it on again started installing packages but stopped with this message:
[image]

And when I hit OK this error happens:

[image]

I have two hdd drives. one HDD for data and one SSD for Ubuntu installation.

This is my setup:

```
❯ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WDS250G1B0A- (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  540MB   538MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 3      540MB   250GB   250GB   ext4


Model: ATA Hitachi HTS72323 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 4      1048kB  10.9GB  10.9GB  extended
 5      1049kB  10.9GB  10.9GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 1      10.9GB  114GB   104GB   primary   ntfs
 2      114GB   241GB   126GB   primary   ntfs
 3      241GB   320GB   79.2GB  primary   ntfs
```

Can I change bios to legacy mode and use it with GTP disk? Does it help?

**UPDATE:**
I tried the upgrade again and I gave this error:

```
This system doesn't support Secure Boot
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
```

Comment: Did you turn on UEFI Secure Boot or an UEFI update reset some settings to defaults which turned it on? Be sure Secure boot is off & boot in UEFI mode only: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks, The problem fixed, I don't know how!! I just executed `dist-upgrade ` again several times and at last no errors.
But I will use Boot-Repair next time. Thanks so much